# Run Time Consuming Tasks in NodeJs/Express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, gruntjs

I need to update some MongoDB Collections in a NodeJs/Express Application which takes too long to process, because it contains iterations and more than 2 thousand API calls.
This task should run once in two weeks. And it should be triggered with an API call, the id of the user who wanted to update the DB should be stored in database.
What is the best way to do this kind of job?

- using task runners
- queueing and messaging
- cronjobs
- your suggestion?

Comment: Is the API public? I would employ a messaging service like AWS SNS.

Comment: ... you could also write a cron style Lambda function.